# Java GUI Swing, buttons in GridLayout without space between buttons

Tags: java, swing, button, layout, grid

I want to create a grid of buttons. Between the buttons there should not be a space, so that the buttons touch the next buttons.

```
import javax.swing.*; 
import java.awt.*; 
import javax.swing.border.*;
public class Bild extends JFrame { 
    public static class createButton extends JPanel { 
        public createButton() {
            JButton b = new JButton(); 
            Border border = new LineBorder(Color.BLACK, 1);
            b.setBorder(border);
            b.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
            b.setPreferredSize (new Dimension(10,10));
            this.add(b); 
        }
    }

    public Bild() {
        GridLayout layout = new GridLayout(10,10,0,0);
        this.setLayout(layout); 
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            this.add(new createButton());
        }
    }
}

import javax.swing.*; 
import java.awt.*; 
public class Main{
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new Bild();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); 
        frame.setSize(500,500);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

with the grid layout I tried to get a 10x10 grid of buttons. But although I created the GridLayout with the parameters 10,10,0,0 there is a space between the buttons.
Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because `createButton` is actually a `JPanel`, which has a [`FlowLayout`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/FlowLayout.html) as it's layout manager by default. Make `createButton` a method that returns a `JButton` and the button will span across the whole space within the cell. (You can remove the `setPreferredSize()`). If you want the buttons to remain 10x10 pixels and be centered within the frame: Set the layout manager of the main panel to a `GridBagLayout` and add a `JPanel` with the `GridLayout` to it. Maybe also override `getPreferredSize()` of the buttons rather than calling `setPreferredSize()`.

---

Buttons spanning across whole screen:

```
class Bild extends JFrame {

    public JButton createButton() {
        JButton b = new JButton();
        Border border = new LineBorder(Color.BLACK, 1);
        b.setBorder(border);
        b.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        return b;
    }

    public Bild() {
        setLayout(new GridLayout(10, 10));
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            add(createButton());
        }
    }
}
```

Buttons remaining 10x10:

```
class Bild extends JFrame {

    public JButton createButton() {
        JButton b = new JButton() {
            @Override
            public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
                return new Dimension(10, 10);
            }
        };
        Border border = new LineBorder(Color.BLACK, 1);
        b.setBorder(border);
        b.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        return b;
    }

    public Bild() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(10, 10));
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            panel.add(createButton());
        }
        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        add(panel);
    }
}
```